# Number of memory types per device

Tags: vulkan

Since `memoryTypeBits` in `VkMemoryRequirements` is a 32 bit uint, does it mean that there can be no more than 32 memory types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, yes. But you pretty much never see more than 12 on actual implementations. There just aren't that many combinations of heaps and memory allocation patterns.

At least, not yet. It's possible that extensions and later core features could balloon this past 32 (much like they had to extend the bits for stages to 64 when they added ray tracing). But thus far, they're pretty far from the limit.

Comment: [VK_MAX_MEMORY_TYPES](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VK_MAX_MEMORY_TYPES)